# InverseFunction

Tags: inverse

Considering a well defined function

```
f[x_]:=Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x] (*x>= 0*)
```

I tried to evaluate the inverse function and get an unexpected result

```
Plot[ InverseFunction[Function[{x}, Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x]]][z] , {z, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

in the range x<0. 
Is this a plotting problem or a bug in InverseFunction?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: `f[x_]:=Tan[Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[x]` is not well defined, as it has a syntax error :)

Comment: Now it's well defined. Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+Tan(sqrt(x))%2Fsqrt(x)) does plot the inverse correctly !

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simply that your inverse is not single valued

```
FindRoot[Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x] == -4 , {x, 2700}]
FindRoot[Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x] == -4 , {x, 23}]
FindRoot[Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x] == -4 , {x, 3}]
```

> 2371.67
>
> 22.7034
>
> 2.94296

`InverseFunction` doesn't always find the lowest..

```
 InverseFunction[Function[{x}, Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x]]][-4] // N
```

> 22.7034 + 0. I

There are actually an infinity of inverses each where `Sqrt[x]` is approximately `n Pi / 2`, `n` odd.

Note if you just want to make the plot you can use

```
ParametricPlot[{Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x], x}, {x, -5, 7},
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Exclusions -> {x == Pi^2/4}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: Thank You, I didn't see it...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction), might be worth reporting. A workaround is to use a black box function instead:

```
f[x_Real]:=Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x]
if = InverseFunction[f[#]&];

Plot[if[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The OP asked about the "missing" inverse when $x<0$. The issue here is that the inverse has multiple branches. The "missing" inverse actually belongs to a different branch. This can be seen by looking at [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot):

```
ContourPlot[
    Tan[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == x, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 30},
    ContourShading->False
]
```

[image]

Rather than trying to come up with an inverse that switches branches, I think it makes more sense to have a different inverse function for each branch. A simple way to do this is to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
(* equation *)
eq[x_] = Tan[Sqrt[y[x]]]/Sqrt[y[x]] == x

(* initial point *)
y2 = y[2] /. First @ NSolve[eq[2] && 15<y[2]<25]

(* NDSolve *)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq'[x], y[2] == y2}, y, {x, -5, 5}];
```

And a visualization:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks: But I'm missing the branch x<0...

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_] := Tan[Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x]

f[0] = f[0.] = Limit[f[x], x -> 0]

(* 1 *)

FunctionDomain[f[x], x]

(* NotElement[1/2 + Sqrt[x]/π, Integers] && x > 0 *)

s = x /. Solve[1/2 + Sqrt[x]/π == 1, x][[1]]

(* π^2/4 *)

if[y_?NumericQ] := x /. NSolve[{f[x] == y, 0 <= x < 10}, x][[1]]

Plot[if[y], {y, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {y, x}),
 Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{-5, s}, {5, s}}]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

`if` (which is to say `NSolve`) fails for some values

```
if[1.00001]

(* Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.

ReplaceAll::reps: {{}[[1]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

x /. {}[[1]] *)
```

Redefine `f` as

```
f2[x_] = Sinc[Sqrt[x]]/Cos[Sqrt[x]];
```

`f` and `f2` are equivalent except that `f2[0]` is defined without adding a separate definition.

```
f[x] == f2[x] // FunctionExpand

(* True *)

f2[0]

(* 1 *)

if2[y_?NumericQ] :=
 x /. NSolve[{f2[x] == y, 0 <= x < 10}, x][[1]]

Plot[if2[y], {y, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {y, x}), 
 Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{-5, s}, {5, s}}]}]
```

[image]

```
if2[1.00001]

(* 0.0000299996 *)
```

Comment: Looks fine, thanks. But near `y=1` I get unexplainable results: `if[1.0001]==0.000299967 (*ok*)`, but  `if[1.00001]==20.1907 (* ??? *)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - Yes. On my Mac with version 11.2.0, `NSolve` fails for `if[1.00001]` and result is `x /.  {}[[1]]` along with associated error messages.